# Getting separate street number and street name from Foursquare search api?

Tags: foursquare

I'm using the Foursquare's venue search API and everything is working as expected. But the response does not contain separate fields for street number and street address. It contains one field named "address" that contains both, like the example below

```
"location": {
  "address": "180 Orchard St",
  "crossStreet": "btwn Houston & Stanton St",
  "lat": 40.72173744277209,
  "lng": -73.98800687282996,
  "labeledLatLngs": [
    {
      "label": "display",
      "lat": 40.72173744277209,
      "lng": -73.98800687282996
    }
  ],
  "distance": 8,
  "postalCode": "10002",
  "cc": "US",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "NY",
  "country": "United States",
  "formattedAddress": [
    "180 Orchard St (btwn Houston & Stanton St)",
    "New York, NY 10002",
    "United States"
  ]
```

I need to have the street number and street name separately. Is there anyway to get a response that has them separated? or the only way is for me to parse it?